# "Finish/complete/resolve an overdue project"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I use the number of results in a Google search of a phrase as a rough estimate of its usage. I googled all three and got:

- "finish an overdue project" — 1920 results
- "complete an overdue project" — 140 results
- "resolve an overdue project" — 0 results

I feel that *resolve* is the most appropriate word in this context since [one of its definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolve) according to Merriam-Webster is:

> **4** a : to deal with successfully : clear up

And according to the Google dictionary:

> **1** Settle or find a solution to (a problem, dispute, or contentious matter)

However, I am worried that this is not standard usage due to the number of Google search results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A project is not usually regarded as a dispute or a contentious issue.  You don't typically *resolve* a project, but you might resolve a *problem* within a project, as the project heads toward completion.

For example:

> *After the drainage problem was resolved, the construction project came to a close.*

Lateness, in and of itself, isn't an issue that needs to be resolved.  Perhaps the *schedule* needs to be resolved, but that's not the same as resolving the project.

Comment: Generally speaking, you resolve the issue that makes the project late.  That's why you're not finding "resolve an overdue project" in your searches. [_this comment was made in response to a question that has since disappeared_].

Comment: +1: Yes, things that need to be "resolved" are usually *"disputes / contentious issues*, or *problems"*. Lateness itself doesn't fall into any relevant category - OP is being misled by the fact that unresolved issues are frequently cited as the *reason* why a project hasn't been completed on schedule (as an excuse, by the very people whose job it is to identify and resolve such issues, imho! :).

Answer (score 1):

Finish and complete are both appropriate, but are not particularly suited to the project and its overdue nature.

Resolve would only be appropriate if the project were subject to some conflict or contention, and even then, it would be more appropriate if directed at that quality or object directly instead of the overdue project itself.

Colloquially, one might say they "made up an overdue project," in the sense that they are "making up" or compensating for their tardiness.